# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined VUE 2.0

Tags: html, vue.js, push

I'm actually taking a tutorial on youtube for Vue.js and I'm stuck on this error
I'm posting a question here for the first time. I apologize in advance if I'm doing it wrong

ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

here is the link to the video tutorial I'm taking and I'm stuck at 47:03
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6hQqgvGI4Y

```js
 <template>
<div class="users">
<h1> Users </h1>

<form v-on:submit="addUser">
<input type="text" v-model="newUser.name" placeholder="Enter name">
<br />
<input type="text" v-model="newUser.email" placeholder="Enter email">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<ul>
<li v-for="user in user">
<input type="checkbox">
{{user.name}}: {{user.email}}<button v-on:click="">delete</button>
</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name: 'users',


  data(){
    return {
    newUser:{},

        user: [{
            name: "Aanif Zia",
            email: "aanif@hotmail.com",
            contacted: false
            },
            {
            name: "Annas Zia",
            email: "annas@gmail.com",
            contacted: false
            },
            {
            name: "Siemel Zia",
            email: "siemel@live.com",
            contacted: false
            }
            ]
          }
        },

    methods: {
addUser: function(e){
this.users.push(
{
name: this.newUser.name,
email: this.newUser.email,
contacted: false,
});
e.preventDefault();
}
              }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: You call this.users.push, you should change the name of the variable in your data to be called users.

Comment: Change this too in your template: `<li v-for="user in users">`

Comment: A.Larsson its fixed. I was stuck here for an hour. I'm an idiot

Comment: Usually when you get `ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined` it's a misspelling somewhere. So always look for that first in those cases. Can also be a problem when referencing something before it's created. Glad you solved it :)